# Extracting optional quantity of words

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a string like this-

```
string="John has got 6 cats but I think my friend Susan has 3 dogs and Mike has 8 fishes"
```

I want to write regex to extract pattern Name verb after it and #of pets and what kind of pets it is.

```
re.findall('[A-Za-z]+ \w+ \d+ \w+', string)
```

works with `Susan has 3 dogs, Mike has 8 fishes`.

But it doesn't work with `John has got 6 cats`

how can I edit code to make it look for one or two words after name?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This sounds more of a use case for NLP rather than just regex as you probably have loads of edge cases around verbs and grammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use non-capturing group `(?:`...`)` and `{1,2}` to denote 1 to 2 repetition as follows

```
import re
string="John has got 6 cats but I think my friend Susan has 3 dogs and Mike has 8 fishes"
found=re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]+ (?:\w+ ){1,2}\d+ \w+', string)
print(found)
```

output

```
['John has got 6 cats', 'Susan has 3 dogs', 'Mike has 8 fishes']
```